# Which electron should be considered the last one?

Tags: orbitals, atomic-structure

Today I came across a problem which asked some quantum number informations regarding the last electron of Zinc.
Now as far as I have studied 4s subshell is filled in preference to 3d subshell bcos of lower energyof 4s subshell. But 4s subshell is located at greater radius than 3d due to greater size of 4s subshell .
Which of the the electrons should be considered the last electron 4s one for the 3d one.

Comment: See https://youtu.be/7hDmtUomFu0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll get to zinc, but first, the ground state electron configuration of ground state gaseous neutral nickel is  [Ar]3d$^8$4s$^2$. Ref 1. Nickel has 28 nuclear protons, two less than zinc. If atomic structures build up linearly, this says that if you put two more protons into the nucleus, you have to fill the 3d shell of electrons, because that's what's empty.

This could also be the electron structure of Zn$^+$$^+$, but isn't! (Ref 2.) "The dication Zn$^+$$^+$ has 30 protons and 28 electrons. The electron configuration of Zn$^+$$^+$ is 1s$^2$2s$^2$2p$^6$3s$^2$3p$^6$3d$^{10}$. (The 4s shell is empty!) Zinc is a d-block transition element. For the d-block elements, the outermost s-sublevel has higher energy than the d-sublevel, which is *contrary* to what the Aufbau diagram

[image]

indicates. When d-block elements lose electrons, they lose the highest energy s electrons first, which in the case of zinc are the two 4s electrons. Having eight 3d electrons and two 4s electrons is much less energetically stable than ten 3d electrons and no 4s electrons." So you fill the 4s shell, because that's what's empty in zinc dication.

"*Contrary*". The bane of students everywhere. What difference does it make, except on tests? And is there any effect on zinc properties?

Let's ask what electrons are the highest energy in zinc metal, rather than trying to discover what electron label we need to neutralize gaseous Zn$^+$ monocation. Metals have atoms swimming in a sea of electrons: "Transition metals tend to have particularly high melting points and boiling points. The reason is that they can involve the 3d electrons in the delocalization as well as the 4s. The more electrons you can involve, the stronger the attractions tend to be." (Ref 3.). What are the labels on the electrons in the sea of zinc electrons? It is said that you can't tell one electron from another because you can't label an electron, but you can *count* electrons!

The boiling point of zinc is unusually low when compared to its neighbors in the periodic table:[image]

This suggests that the number of electrons in the zinc sea is low, like 2 per atom, rather than high, like 10 or 12 per atom. So the additional 2 protons in zinc compared to nickel switches the energies of the 3d and 4s shells - with all those nodes and electron amplitudes interacting, it's a wonder that chemistry is as organized as it is!

The data point to the 4s level as the last to be filled.

Ref 1. https://www.webelements.com/nickel/atoms.html

Ref 2. https://socratic.org/questions/what-is-the-electron-configuration-for-zn2

Ref 3. https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Bellarmine_University/BU%3A_Chem_103_(Christianson)/Phase_3%3A_Atoms_and_Molecules_-_the_Underlying_Reality/9%3A_Chemical_Bonding/9.5%3A_Metallic_Bonding